# Regexp for mentions in HTML content

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to do a regexp for catch the mention in a HTML content. I have a content like this:

```
<div data-user-id="@john">@john</div>
```

I want catch only the mention inside the divs, not inside the `""`. I've done this regexp (http://regexr.com/3ckv8):

```
/[^"]@[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[^"]/g
```

That works almost fine. The problem is that it catch also the `><` of the div tags. Any suggestion?

Comment: The best is to use an HTML parser. What is the language you are using?

Comment: just post expected output ?

Comment: How about using `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML` method of DOM ?

Comment: What if you could get that from DOM, is it ok?

Comment: Try with neg. lookahead and word boundary: `@\w+\b(?!")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your suggestion was the best...I've parsed HTML before and then used a simpler regexp for catch "@mentions"

Comment: Good, then plesse try removing this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '<div data-user-id="@john">@john</div>';
preg_match_all('#<div.*?>([^>]*)</div>#i', $str, $match_arr); 
print_r($match_arr[1], 1);
```

and for JS side solution

```
<div id="data" data-user-id="@john">@john</div>
$("#data").text();
```

Comment: Not a good idea, because this is totally server side(btw I use JS on client-side)

Answer (score 0):

With the limited power of JS's regex's, I'm thinking the best bet is two steps:

1. Get the content of the `<div>` with DOM calls (or a regex if this is in a non-DOM situation)
2. Then use this regex `/(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/g` on the div contents *(the refs wil  be in `\1 \2 ...`)*

Comment: Yes, thank you, it got lost in the cut-n-paste somehow

Comment: For me, it is more a comment. I already commented that DOM parser is best for this task. The regex provided in the answer will not help.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew -- how so?

Comment: See what OP wants: *I want catch only the mention inside the divs, **not inside the ""**.*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've already reply above, but your suggestion, was the best solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, and my first step was to extract the **contents** of the div, and then use a regex.